# Pass model item id to jquery function from Html.ActionLink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to be able to pass the id of each item in below code to jQuery function using Html.ActionLink().

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (item.AppointmentStatus == "P")
        {   
        <div class="appointment-main-block" role="menuitem" tabindex="20">
            <div class="appointment-heading">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Speciality)
            </div>
            <div class="appointmenttitle">
                Date
               <br />
                <br />
                Clinician
               <br />
                <br />
                Location
            </div>
            <div class="appointmentdata">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AppointmentDate)
                <br />
                <br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClinicianName)
                <br />
                <br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)
            </div>

            <div class="appointmentbutton appointmentbuttonclickable">
                View @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Details", "MyAppointments",  new { id = item.AppointmentIdentifier.id }, new { onclick = "getAppointmentRef( item.AppointmentIdentifier.id)" })
                <br />
                <img src="/Content/images/icons/view.png" alt="view icon" />
            </div>
        </div>
        }
    }

// jQuery - Very Basic for now also considered
$(".appointmentbutton").click(getAppointmentRef);
    function getAppointmentRef(id) {
                alert(id);
            }
```

The function is called ok but even if I pass a 'hello' it seems to pass an JSON string none of whose params are the 'id'  i,e. 123456789

How do I make the Actionlink pick up the id for that model item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you have a syntax error there. This, I believe, should read:

```
onclick = "getAppointmentRef( @item.AppointmentIdentifier.id)"
```

Or

```
onclick = "getAppointmentRef( " + @item.AppointmentIdentifier.id + ")"
```

One of the two.

However, principally I would take a different approach:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link text", "Details", "MyAppointments",  new { id = item.AppointmentIdentifier.id }, new { @class = "myLink", data_id = item.AppointmentIdentifier.id })
```

Then in jQuery:

```
$(".myLink").click(function () {
    alert($(this).data("id"));
});
```

That way, you have a much clearer separation of concerns.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Seems redundant to use Razor to make an ActionLink and then fire a jQuery click function.  I would either make an input element with a jQuery event handler or get rid of the jQuery function all together, as it wouldn't really be necessary if you are just changing the page anyway

Comment: I agree. However, I am simply educating ConfusedShark on a way to intermingle jQuery and Model values with best practice principles. I am sure this won't be their eventual code as it doesn't make much sense at present.

Comment: I'd also use `$(this).data("id")`

Comment: Good suggestion Lars, updating now.

Comment: Thanks a lot guts does the trick perfectly and I can expand the function now. I did have the click function jquery event handler in my code but had switched to onclick as a starter to get it working before adjusting back. I'm not actually passing the id in he url but just included it in the example to show it was able to do this successfully.

Answer (score 0):

For your button you can use something like -

```
<input type="button" data-apptid="@item.AppointmentIdentifier.id" class="myLink" value="Click me!" />
```

And your jQuery could be like Moby mentioned -

```
$(".myLink").click(function () {
    document.location.href = "/MyAppointments/Details/" & $(this).data("apptid");
});
```

This way if you needed to do something in jQuery besides just load the new page, you could do it there and have the function determine whether you redirect or not.